Connecting a Wix Domain to an Hostinger webite
One of my client bought domain from wix and I designed a website for him and it hosted on hostinger with dummy domain, How Can I connect wix domain to hostinger website because there is no option change server name on wix.
Please help me how can I connect my hostinger webiste on wix domain?

If you want to change the NS records of a domain in Wix you can't do it, Wix is not a domain provider so you need to take it outside of Wix. You should connect that domain to another place like Squarespace domains, Godaddy or somewhere else.
